# Knockout.js: how to make a variable available to all viewmodels so it can be used in bindings without explicitly putting it in all viewmodels?

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

I am refactoring code base based on Knockout.js and have stumped into a problem. 
The code uses templates as interpolated strings in typescript eg.

```
var template = `<div title='${Resources.string1}'> ${Resources.string1} </div>`
```

The problem is that the strings can contain a single quote which sometimes break the proper HTML parsing after it has been compiled to javascript.

```
var template = `<div title='I have a ' single quote'> I have a ' single quote</div>`
```

I want to expose the Resources object so that it is visible in all the view models without explicitly adding the resource object to every view model  so that I can use it like this

```
<div data-bind="title: Resource.string1"> ${Resources.string1} </div>
```

Or is their anything global to which I can bind this resources object and access it from all view models inside my app.

Comment: Probably you can use $root object (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) as a container to hold global objects.

Comment: When you are talking about all view models do you mean they are all sub view models of a main view model or they are individual view models?

Comment: @Matt.kaaj They are individual view models.

Comment: You can send it by using your template engine depends on your environment (razor asp.net, blade laravel jade node.js,...) or have it in a separate view model which is loaded on all pages as default.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to a global variable without any problem.

This one works, here is a demo [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/292xsz8c/1/).

```
var Resources = {
  string1: "something here with ' quote"
}
window.Resources = Resources;

ko.applyBindings({});

<div data-bind="text: Resources.string1">
</div>
```

However, this feels like kind of a hack. I'd rather use some HTML encoding for the resources. See some possibilities [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery). I'd add a `getResource` function which would return the requested resource in a properly encoded form.